# Multiple nested if Statements vs Logical AND in compare function

Tags: c++

I've got a question to clarify myself. I checked some posts on Stackoverflow but I couldn't figure out
and exact answer for that since this might be a 'compilerthing'.

Suppose I have a class which has many attributes and I wanted to write a compare() Function.
So the compare() function could look like this:

```
bool compare(const Object& a, const Object& b)
{
    return a.attr1 == b.attr1 && a.attr2 == b.attr2 ..... ;
}
```

But I could also write it like this:

```
bool compare(const Object& a, const Object& b)
{
    if (a.attr1 == b.attr1)
        if (a.ttr2 == b.attr2)
            ....
            return true;

    return false;    
}
```

I tend to do the first one but I see code like the second one and ask myself if there is any benefit to writing it that way.
I am using msvc2019.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const auto as_tuple = [](const Object& o){ return std::tie(o.attr1, o.attr2 /*...*/);} return as_tuple(a) == as_tuple(b);`.

Comment: Unless evil operator overloads, there are similar (short circuit for `&&`). first one seems more readable.

Comment: Logical operators && and || are short-circuiting. If you can deduce the result without checking all the comparisons, they will be skipped, so the code above and below are pretty equivalent. You can read more about it there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.

Note, that an easier way to write a comparison like that would be to `std::tie` the elements you want to compare:
`return std::tie(a.attr1, a.attr2, (some more...)) == std::tie(b.attr1, b.attr2, (some more...));`

Comment: There's no benefit, but many people seem uncomfortable around booleans (I see a lot of `if (foo == true) return true; else return false;` even among very senior programmers). Also, the logical operators don't always follow common human intuition, which can cause some to shun them in uncertain situations. (And, of course, sometimes the logic is sufficiently complex that expressing it with operators alone is an unreadable mess.)

Comment: Wellt, thanks a lot guys!